# Add texts between Images render by ngFor - Angular 5

Tags: angular

I have 3 images that render by this code ***ngFor**

```
<img *ngFor="let resource of task.resourceList"
        [src]="imagePath+resource.iconPath" alt="user" class="img-responsive radius m-r-10" style="width:40px; cursor:default;">
```

which will render this

[image]

I want to at least place the arrows `>>` between those icons how would one do that in Angular ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the expanded syntax for `ngFor` along with `last`:

```
<ng-template ngFor let-resource let-last="last" [ngForOf]="task.resourceList"> 
   <img [src]="imagePath+resource.iconPath" alt="user" class="img-responsive radius m-r-10" style="width:40px; cursor:default;">
   <span *ngIf="!last"> &gt;&gt; </span>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
<span *ngFor="let resource of task.resourceList; last as isLast">
  <img [src]="imagePath+resource.iconPath" 
       alt="user" 
       class="img-responsive radius m-r-10" 
       style="width:40px; cursor:default;">

  {{ isLast ? '' : ' >>> ' }}
</span>
```

you can also wrap both image and span with arrows in a single `ngFor`

Comment: You `>>>` is not rendering in between but at the end.

Comment: yeah, my mistake, it should be wrapped with `ngFor`, updated my answer

Comment: I will try that. your answer is also good, because you kept a lot of my original code. Thanks guys.